# Jetty 9.4.4 or above causes Servlet not Found 404 Error

Tags: servlets, jetty

When I upgrade to Jetty 9.4.4 or greater I get a new error 404 on some of my Servlets. All is fine till this specific version. Has anyone encountered this problem, too? Luckily I am able to pin the version to 9.4.3, but I would like to resolve this issue if possible.

I use Maven and Netbeans to build the JEE 7.0 Application. It is deployed as WAR file on a Server running Jetty in a Docker container.

The Servlet is defined as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/WebNumberCheckServlet")
public class WebNumberCheckServlet extends AbstractWebBaseServlet {
```

where AbstractWebBaseServlet is:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public abstract class AbstractWebBaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

web.xml is only used for realm config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>de.lindawerner.pimp.pimpserver.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/stats.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>AppOnlineServerRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Administrator</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Comment: Not enough information to go on.  How is the servlet defined/configured/declared?  What servlet?  How are you deploying/configuration the webapp?

Comment: Same error here ! any solution ?